# Java : jscrollpane disable horizontal scrolling

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane

I want to add a Jpanel on a jscrollpane; also I want to have only vertical scrolling. I want to set layout of my jPanel "flowLaout" and add several components to my jPanel in my code by jpanel.add(component) method. The result is that all components are placed in just one row that excide width of jpanel and are not shown. I have used this tricks and both failed:

```
jScrollPane1.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);
jScrollPane1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) should work for you.

Comment: No It doesn't work. Horizontal Scroll ability is disabled but I components are shown in one row. JPanel layout is flowlayout.

Comment: @sajad, The code works fine for me otherwise I wouldn't have posted the code on the blog. So post your SSCCE that dmononstrates your problem so I can see if the problem is the WrapLayout or your code for using the WrapLayout.

Comment: Sorry, first i didn't notice link. I thought you refer my code. But this works correctly as you said. Thanks a lot Mr!

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure of the particulars for your current project, but i would recommend [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/). It has never served me wrong.

I am currently writing a touchscreen interface with nested MigLayout panels up to 4 or five layers deep, and have not had a single problem.

Comment: It is probably good idea. thank you. I just tried previous answer and my problem solved. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below policy to turn on vertical scrolling and turn off horizontal scrolling(Works with Java SE 7):

```
Panel graphicPanel = new Panel();
JScrollPane scrollbar = new JScrollPane(graphicPanel);
scrollbar.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
scrollbar.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
scrollbar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1300, 600));
scrollbar.setVisible(true);
add(scrollbar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```